# Sparql query from java code to retrieve result from owl file

Tags: java, sparql, owl

I am new to sparql query. I have the following query. I am trying to retrieve range and domain from owl file. I am getting output in protege. But for the same query I am not getting any output in eclipse.

This is a very simple ontology.

I am just having 3 classes. Water, Herd and pasture

One object property - req

I have defined herd and pasture as domain for obejct property "req" and water as range.

When I execute the below query in protege, i am getting herd and pasture as output for domains, water for range. But in java, it simply prints range and domain headers.

Can anyone assist me regarding this? Thanks in advance. Below is the code in eclipse. I tried saving file in RDF format as well as owl. But no luck.

```
OntModel model1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
File file=new File("C:\\Users\\anithat\\Desktop\\finalcheck.owl");
FileInputStream reader=new FileInputStream(file);
model1.read(reader,null);
    
String queryString =    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" + 
        "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "+ 
        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.semanticweb.org/anithat/ontologies/2020/6/untitled-ontology-30#>" +
        "SELECT ?range ?domain { rdfs:req rdfs:domain ?domain . "
        + "rdfs:req rdfs:range ?water .}";
            
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);
ResultSet resultset = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, resultset, query);
```

Comment: you select `?range ?domain` but in your query you use `?water` instead of `?range` - please fix this first

Comment: the reason why you don't get a result is that you reused the `rdfs` prefix, which is bad practice - your example shows some pitfalls. RDFS has it's own namespace and usually people use prefix `rdfs` for it. But you used your own namespace with the prefix `rdfs` which means the property `rdfs:range` is a property  with the URI in`http://www.semanticweb.org/anithat/ontologies/2020/6/untitled-ontology-30#range` from your ontology which clearly does not exist.

Comment: Please use your own prefi, e.g. `ex:` or `myOnt:` or whatever. And then add the prefix declaration for `rdfs:` with its correct namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#`

Comment: and the query definitely does **not** work in Protege, at least not the exact query shown here.